# Upgrade Rancher 2 workload using Rancher API

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubectl, rancher

I have created a workload on Rancher. This workload created from an image which taken from Azure Container Registry and getting the variables and all the specifications from Helm chart thats being uploaded to Chartmuseum.

So far we are doing the upgrade by hand and want to transition to use the CI to orchestrate this process.

The desired outcome is to use the rancher API to upgrade the template version `:latest` from the Chartmuseum, adding picture as reference:
[image: Template Version, reference]

As for the orchestrator of the CI we are using Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually**, Azure Devops has integrated **Rancher** into CL/CD task. You could install [that extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ThiagoBarradas.rancher) and use it to upgrade the template version under pipeline task.